¿Como generar la matriz de conteos tras aplicar un alineamiento con Bowtie2?
Después de haber realizado un alineamiento con Bowtie2 y pasar todos los archivos sam a bam con samtools, intento realizar con el siguiente codigo la matriz de conteo:
pacman::p_load(Rsamtools,GenomicFeatures,GenomicAlignments,org.Hs.eg.db)
gtfFile = "Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.112.gff3"
txdb = makeTxDbFromGFF(gtfFile, format="gff3")
genes = exonsBy(txdb, by="gene")
indir = getwd()
files = list.files(indir, pattern = '*sort.bam')
bamLst = BamFileList(files, index=character(),obeyQname=TRUE)
PRJNA411984 = summarizeOverlaps(features = genes,
read=bamLst,
mode="Union",
singleEnd=FALSE,
ignore.strand=TRUE,
fragments=FALSE)
save(PRJNA1021663,file="PRJNA1021663.rda")

Y me da el siguiente error:
Import genomic features from the file as a GRanges object ... OK
Prepare the 'metadata' data frame ... OK
Make the TxDb object ... OK
Avisos:
1: In .get_cds_IDX(mcols0$type, mcols0$phase) :
The "phase" metadata column contains non-NA values for features of type
stop_codon. This information was ignored.
2: In .extract_transcripts_from_GRanges(tx_IDX, gr, mcols0$type, mcols0$ID,
:
the transcript names ("tx_name" column in the TxDb object) imported
from the "transcript_id" attribute are not unique
Error en reducer$value.cache[[as.character(idx)]] <- values:
argumentos inválidos para sub-asignación de entorno
Calls: summarizeOverlaps ... .bploop_impl -> .collect_result -> .reducer_add
-> .reducer_add
Además: Aviso:
In parallel::mccollect(wait = FALSE, timeout = 1) :
1 parallel job did not deliver a result
Ejecución interrumpida
Error al cerrar parallel: no se pueden finalizar algunos procesos hijos
